# How to find the div before a specified element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

```
<td>
    <div class="resumehint"></div>
    <input type="file" id="resume" />
</td>
```

How to get the div before "#resume" with jQuery?

That is ".resumehint"

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
$(this).prev("div")
```

or

```
$(this).prev()
```

or

```
$(this).prev(".resumehint")
```

you can replace `$(this)` with `$('#resume')` if you are outside a function.

Comment: $('#resume').prevAll()

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Traversing/prev](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prev) function:

```
$('#resume').prev('div');
```

And if you know the CSS class of the div to be more specific:

```
$('#resume').prev('div.resumehint');
```

Answer (score 5):

for multiple elements:

```
$('#resume').prevAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#resume").prev();
```